# Passing Form data from outside to CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, php-5.5

I am trying to pass a form data like name, email from simple html page to a CodeIgniter application. 
Direcotry Structute:
SampleDir

- CodeIgniterApp
- Form.html

I am trying to pass form (POST) and recieve inside the CodeIgniter. I am new to CodeIgniter and trying to connect my app to third party app. From what I searched CodeIgniter has controllers and views. Controllers being called first which inturn load up the view.

I tried

```
$view = array (
                'available_services'    => $available_services,
                'available_providers'   => $available_providers,
                'company_name'          => $company_name,
                'manage_mode'           => $manage_mode,
                'appointment_data'      => $appointment,
                'provider_data'         => $provider,
                'customer_data'         => $customer,
                'post_data'             => json_decode($_POST)
            );
```

and passing it to view, but it does not shows up.

HTML Code:

```
<form action="/appointment" method="POST" target="_blank">
            <div style="display:none!important;">
                <input type="text" placeholder="name" name="name" id="name" ng-model="cust.name">
                <input type="text" placeholder="email" name="email" id="email" ng-model="cust.email">
                <input type="text" placeholder="telephone" name="phone" id="phone" ng-model="cust.phone">
            </div>

            <div class="text-center btn-toolbar" style="margin-top: 30px;">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="cancel()" style="font-size: 20px;">OK</button>
                <button type="submit" name="process" class="btn btn-success" style="font-size: 20px;">Schedule a Call</button>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Controller Code:

```
public function index($appointment_hash = '') {
    // echo $this->input->post('email');
    var_dump($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']);
    if (!$this->check_installation()) return;

    $this->load->model('appointments_model');
    $this->load->model('providers_model');
    $this->load->model('services_model');
    $this->load->model('customers_model');
    $this->load->model('settings_model');

    if (strtoupper($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) !== 'POST') { 
        try {
            $available_services  = $this->services_model->get_available_services();
            $available_providers = $this->providers_model->get_available_providers();
            $company_name        = $this->settings_model->get_setting('company_name');

            // If an appointment hash is provided then it means that the customer 
            // is trying to edit a registered appointment record.
            if ($appointment_hash !== ''){ 
                // Load the appointments data and enable the manage mode of the page.
                $manage_mode = TRUE;

                $results = $this->appointments_model->get_batch(array('hash' => $appointment_hash));

                if (count($results) === 0) {
                    // The requested appointment doesn't exist in the database. Display
                    // a message to the customer.
                    $view = array(
                        'message_title' => $this->lang->line('appointment_not_found'),
                        'message_text'  => $this->lang->line('appointment_does_not_exist_in_db'),
                        'message_icon'  => $this->config->item('base_url') 
                                         . '/assets/img/error.png'
                    );
                    $this->load->view('appointments/message', $view);                        
                    return;
                }

                $appointment = $results[0]; 
                $provider = $this->providers_model->get_row($appointment['id_users_provider']);
                $customer = $this->customers_model->get_row($appointment['id_users_customer']);

            } else {
                // The customer is going to book a new appointment so there is no 
                // need for the manage functionality to be initialized.
                $manage_mode        = FALSE;
                $appointment   = array();
                $provider      = array();
                $customer      = array();
            }

            // Load the book appointment view.
            $view = array (
                'available_services'    => $available_services,
                'available_providers'   => $available_providers,
                'company_name'          => $company_name,
                'manage_mode'           => $manage_mode,
                'appointment_data'      => $appointment,
                'provider_data'         => $provider,
                'customer_data'         => $customer,
                'post_data'             => json_decode($_POST)
            );

        } catch(Exception $exc) {
            $view['exceptions'][] = $exc;
        }

        $this->load->view('appointments/book', $view);

    } else { 
        // The page is a post-back. Register the appointment and send notification emails
        // to the provider and the customer that are related to the appointment. If google 
        // sync is enabled then add the appointment to the provider's account.

        try {
            $post_data = json_decode($_POST['post_data'], true);
            $appointment = $post_data['appointment'];
            $customer = $post_data['customer'];

            if ($this->customers_model->exists($customer)) 
                    $customer['id'] = $this->customers_model->find_record_id($customer);

            $customer_id = $this->customers_model->add($customer);
            $appointment['id_users_customer'] = $customer_id; 

            $appointment['id'] = $this->appointments_model->add($appointment);
            $appointment['hash'] = $this->appointments_model->get_value('hash', $appointment['id']);

            $provider = $this->providers_model->get_row($appointment['id_users_provider']);
            $service = $this->services_model->get_row($appointment['id_services']);

            $company_settings = array( 
                'company_name'  => $this->settings_model->get_setting('company_name'),
                'company_link'  => $this->settings_model->get_setting('company_link'),
                'company_email' => $this->settings_model->get_setting('company_email')
            );

            // :: SYNCHRONIZE APPOINTMENT WITH PROVIDER'S GOOGLE CALENDAR
            // The provider must have previously granted access to his google calendar account  
            // in order to sync the appointment.
            try {
                $google_sync = $this->providers_model->get_setting('google_sync', 
                        $appointment['id_users_provider']);

                if ($google_sync == TRUE) {
                    $google_token = json_decode($this->providers_model
                            ->get_setting('google_token', $appointment['id_users_provider']));

                    $this->load->library('google_sync');
                    $this->google_sync->refresh_token($google_token->refresh_token);

                    if ($post_data['manage_mode'] === FALSE) {
                        // Add appointment to Google Calendar.
                        $google_event = $this->google_sync->add_appointment($appointment, $provider, 
                                $service, $customer, $company_settings);
                        $appointment['id_google_calendar'] = $google_event->id;
                        $this->appointments_model->add($appointment); 
                    } else {
                        // Update appointment to Google Calendar.
                        $appointment['id_google_calendar'] = $this->appointments_model
                                ->get_value('id_google_calendar', $appointment['id']);

                        $this->google_sync->update_appointment($appointment, $provider,
                                $service, $customer, $company_settings);
                    }
                }  
            } catch(Exception $exc) {
                $view['exceptions'][] = $exc;
            }

            // :: SEND NOTIFICATION EMAILS TO BOTH CUSTOMER AND PROVIDER
            try {
                $this->load->library('Notifications');

                $send_provider = $this->providers_model
                        ->get_setting('notifications', $provider['id']);

                if (!$post_data['manage_mode']) {
                    $customer_title = $this->lang->line('appointment_booked');
                    $customer_message = $this->lang->line('thank_you_for_appointment');
                    $customer_link = $this->config->item('base_url') . '/index.php/appointments/index/' 
                            . $appointment['hash'];

                    $provider_title = $this->lang->line('appointment_added_to_your_plan');
                    $provider_message = $this->lang->line('appointment_link_description');
                    $provider_link = $this->config->item('base_url') . '/index.php/backend/index/' 
                            . $appointment['hash'];
                } else {
                    $customer_title = $this->lang->line('appointment_changes_saved');
                    $customer_message = '';
                    $customer_link = $this->config->item('base_url') . '/index.php/appointments/index/' 
                            . $appointment['hash'];

                    $provider_title = $this->lang->line('appointment_details_changed');
                    $provider_message = '';
                    $provider_link = $this->config->item('base_url') . '/index.php/backend/index/' 
                            . $appointment['hash'];
                }

                $this->notifications->send_appointment_details($appointment, $provider, 
                        $service, $customer,$company_settings, $customer_title, 
                        $customer_message, $customer_link, $customer['email']);

                if ($send_provider == TRUE) {
                    $this->notifications->send_appointment_details($appointment, $provider, 
                            $service, $customer, $company_settings, $provider_title, 
                            $provider_message, $provider_link, $provider['email']);
                }
            } catch(Exception $exc) {
                $view['exceptions'][] = $exc;
            }

            // :: LOAD THE BOOK SUCCESS VIEW
            $view = array(
                'appointment_data'  => $appointment,
                'provider_data'     => $provider,
                'service_data'      => $service,
                'company_name'      => $company_settings['company_name']
            );

        } catch(Exception $exc) {
            $view['exceptions'][] = $exc;
        }

        $this->load->view('appointments/book_success', $view);
    }   
}
$this->load->view('appointments/book', $view);
```

To be more precise, this the the app I am trying to connect to https://github.com/alextselegidis/easyappointments

If the root src folder is appointment, then http://localhost/appointment takes me to appointment/application/views/appointments/book.php and appointment/application/controllers/appointments.php

Have a look and suggest what to do.

Comment: where are all those variables you're using in that array coming from?  we'll need to see that part of the code....

Comment: Strange: When I am doing var_dump($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']); I am getting 'GET' on the view

Comment: @Rooster: edited the question with controller code or see https://github.com/alextselegidis/easyappointments/blob/master/src/application/controllers/appointments.php

Comment: The correct way to fetch post data in codeigniter is with `$this->input->post('input_name');` Also you don't need to json_decode() your post data if you just send the form without json encoding them first.

Answer (score 0):

I have this trouble too, you have to add this line on your code:

```
$_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);
```

that would let you use json on code igniter post so after that line you can do

```
$this->input->post('yourkey')
```

and you will get the things you want :)

Comment: Nope. I am getting bool(false) when I do $_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);
        var_dump($this->input->post('name'));

Comment: Why -1 ? i just trying to help you i have the same problem , are you seding json data to the code igniter endpoint ? pls Add a print of your $_POST (var_dump($_POST)) to see what you have

Comment: I didn't do it. Sorry. if accidetly done. I really appreciate your help and thanks. Your suggestions helped to move forward and solve the key. but I didn't have to use $_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);